# How to make buttons responsive in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

I am a beginner in Android and want to build 4 buttons on the bottom like in the picture. One button in the middle is not possible because I tried to set it responsive and it disappeared. Can you explain to me how I set those buttons next to each other with the same distance and make it responsive the right way?

[image]

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f4f4f4"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:text="This app has 50000 downloads!"
    android:textColor="#eadca6"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.70"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.86" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.77" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button13" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintHeigth_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button13" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button13" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:text="This app has 50000 downloads!"
        android:textColor="#eadca6"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.70"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.86" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.77" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="One"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnTwo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnThree"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnOne" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Three"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnFour"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnTwo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFour"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Four"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnThree" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image] . [image]

Comment: Cool, thank you! But how can I make the buttons higher? Without using fixed sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to *Nilesh Rathod*  answer you can do something like this if you want to control the button height your :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#f4f4f4"
  tools:context="MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:text="This app has 50000 downloads!"
    android:textColor="#eadca6"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.70"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.77" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="One"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnTwo"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Two"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnOne"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnThree"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnOne"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnOne" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnThree"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Three"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnOne"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnFour"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnTwo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnOne" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFour"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Four"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnOne"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnThree"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnOne" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now `btnOne` got the height of 10% of the screen height, all other buttons are constrained to top of `btnOne` and have the `android:layout_height="0dp"` attribute, making them all the same size.

And if you want to change your button size just change the value of `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"` on `btnOne`

**Here is how it will look like**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try adding all the buttons inside a linear layout with it's orientation set to horizontal and the buttons will take i
Equal distance. To make buttons responsive use the `onclicklistener();` to get the response

Comment: The linearlayout makes sense, but I cannot use app:layout_constraintWidth_percent inside it. Also, what has the onClickListener to do with responsive layout?

Comment: Your not supposed to next View groups in a constraint layout